# Buddypress Members Directory Page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have buddypress installed in wordpress and Paid Membership Pro.
When someone registers they use the buddypress reg from with some additional profile fields I added to collect info then after registration they choose a paid or free membership level via the paid membership pro plugin.

So now I want to display a list of users that signed up for a free or paid membership. The default buddypress page domain.com/members shows all registered users whether they choose a membership level or not. Some spammers just registered so I don't want to display those, only users that continued and chose a membership level.

I would like to show ONLY users that have completed the checkout and chose a membership level (not just registered) and also display which level they purchased next to their name.

By default it appears that the members page shows an avatar, the users name and last activity.
I would like to also maybe remove the activity and add a couple of the custom profile fields I added to the buddypress registration form.

I assume I could maybe update the members-loop.php page ?

Or is there a better way?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way of doing it than updating members-loop.php. You can hook to the `bp_ajax_querystring` filter. For example:

```
function my_exclude_users_filter( $query = false, $object = false ) {
    // manipulate the query however you like
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'bp_ajax_querystring', 'my_exclude_users_filter', 30, 2 );
```

Hope this gives you a good example of how it can be done.